# SQL XML modify replace

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need help in replacing the XML tag value. Sample code is as follows:

```
declare @l_runtime_xml XML
declare @l_n_DrillRepID numeric(10)
declare @griddrillparam nvarchar(30)
declare @l_s_DrillBtColumnTag nvarchar(256)
declare @l_s_BTNameSecond nvarchar(30)

set @l_n_DrillRepID =1538
set @griddrillparam = 'userID'
set @l_s_DrillBtColumnTag = 'V_userID'
set @l_s_BTNameSecond = 'l_s_userID'

declare @l_runtime_xmlAAA nvarchar(max)
set @l_runtime_xmlAAA = N'<REPORT_RUNTIME_XML><USER_ID>AISHU</USER_ID><SHEET><SHEET_NO>1</SHEET_NO><DRILLTHRU_PARAM><ENT_RPT><ENT_RPT_ID>1537</ENT_RPT_ID><ENT_RPT_NAME>Reddy111</ENT_RPT_NAME><DEFAULT>1</DEFAULT><CRITERIA><DISPLAY/><HIDDEN/></CRITERIA><COLUMN_HEADER>N</COLUMN_HEADER><DISPLAY_BUTTON>N</DISPLAY_BUTTON><PARAMLIST><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>userID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_userID>(none)</V_userID></PARAM><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>langID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_langID>(none)</V_langID></PARAM><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>l_s_userID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_l_s_userID>(none)</V_l_s_userID></PARAM><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>a_i_langID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_a_i_langID>(none)</V_a_i_langID></PARAM></PARAMLIST></ENT_RPT><ENT_RPT><ENT_RPT_ID>1538</ENT_RPT_ID><ENT_RPT_NAME>Reddy333</ENT_RPT_NAME><DEFAULT>0</DEFAULT><CRITERIA><DISPLAY/><HIDDEN/></CRITERIA><COLUMN_HEADER>N</COLUMN_HEADER><DISPLAY_BUTTON>N</DISPLAY_BUTTON><PARAMLIST><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>userID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_userID>(none)</V_userID></PARAM><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>langID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_langID>(none)</V_langID></PARAM><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>l_s_userID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_l_s_userID>(none)</V_l_s_userID></PARAM><PARAM><COLTYPE/><POSITION>-999</POSITION><BT_COLUMN_NAME/><NAME>a_i_langID</NAME><BT_NAME/><V_a_i_langID>(none)</V_a_i_langID></PARAM></PARAMLIST></ENT_RPT></DRILLTHRU_PARAM></SHEET></REPORT_RUNTIME_XML>'

select @l_runtime_xml = cast(@l_runtime_xmlAAA as XML)  

SET @l_runtime_xml.modify('replace value of ((//SHEET/DRILLTHRU_PARAM/ENT_RPT[(ENT_RPT_ID/text())[1] eq sql:variable("@l_n_DrillRepID")]/PARAMLIST/PARAM[(NAME/text())[1] eq sql:variable("@griddrillparam")]/@l_s_DrillBtColumnTag))[1] with sql:variable("@l_s_BTNameSecond")')

set @l_runtime_xmlAAA = cast(@l_runtime_xml as nvarchar(max))

select @l_runtime_xmlAAA
```

Comment: Or, is it possible to delete the last child of a node?

Comment: Can you please explain the required replace logic in words and where it is going wrong.    And yes, it is possible to delete the last node.   Which do you want answered, the deletion or the replacement

Comment: Thanks @PhilB. primarily i needed replacements only. And i got it how to do. I was asking for delete as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is here:

```
.../@l_s_DrillBtColumnTag))[1]
```

If I understand this correctly, you are trying to access an element of the name "V_userId" by putting a variable in that place. But this will not work...

Your question is not quite clear to me (and admittably your structure isn't either, it seems too complicated...). And what do you mean with *delete the last child of a node*?

Your query would be the following:

Find the "ENT_RPT" with the given number, there find the "PARAM" whose name is what's given and on the same level find the element with the name given, which is to be replaced (see `local-name()`). Replace this with the value given:

```
SET @l_runtime_xml.modify('replace value of (//SHEET/DRILLTHRU_PARAM/ENT_RPT[ENT_RPT_ID/text()=sql:variable("@l_n_DrillRepID")]/PARAMLIST/PARAM[NAME/text()=sql:variable("@griddrillparam")]/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@l_s_DrillBtColumnTag")]/text())[1] with sql:variable("@l_s_BTNameSecond")')
```

On the first sigth I assume, that you are dealing with named parameters. It was much better to put the value of these parameters in an element with the same name for all of them (e.g. `<VALUE>something</VALUE>`. They are specified via "NAME" anyway.

And even better was a structure with attributes, something like

```
...<PARAM Name="userName" position="-999" moreAttributes...>SomeValue</PARAM>
```

This would make your navigation much easier and less erronous...